# 'str' object has no attribute 'exec_module'

Tags: python, python-importlib

I'm trying to import script code in a test.py file as a module using importlib in google colab.
Here's my code:

```
def load_module(file_name, module_name):
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(module_name, file_name)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    print(spec.loader)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    return module
def get_file(path):
    SCRIPT_FILE = open(path,'r')
    return SCRIPT_FILE
```

I run above function for getting for getting lib from test.py

```
file =get_file('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/test/test.py')
module = load_module("from lib import *\n" + file.read(),'crawl')
```

And I got this error

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'exec_module'
```

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 2, you are passing in type `string` instead of type `Loader` for the second function argument. If you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py#L422), it looks like the loader is not being generated based on your path:

`spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(module_name, file_name)`

[Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/test/test_importlib/extension/test_loader.py#L112) is a sample implementation of using `spec_from_loader`, by generating a loader with `ExtensionFileFinder`.

However, for *your* use case, can you try using [`spec_from_file_location`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.spec_from_file_location)? This way, you can see if it can generate your spec based on the file path you passed in. Try passing the path into the [`location`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f4c03484da59049eb62a9bf7777b963e2267d187/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py#L735) argument.

Comment: I want convert my .py file into module and call it like "from test import *" for getting all lib define in test.py file, but spec_from_file_location cannot doing that stuff